# print a message to the terminal when the user changes to a specific directory?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, administration

Is it possible, in unix, to make it so that a system message appears once a user has changed (cd) to a particular directory?

I know about motd, but I'm wondering if there is something similar to that for navigating in the shell. For instance, if I typed

```
cd /etc/apache2/
```

a message could be printed to the screen...something like:

> "The latest configuration modified in this directory was..."
>   "Please be careful modifying ... and ..."

something that all users could potentially see?

Comment: You could alias `cd` to a custom function.

Comment: And I am not sure it is a good idea. (making `cd` a function is not bulletproof) Your users should learn the common habits of Unix (including the fact that a successful command is usually silent). I would suggest changing the interactive prompt (e.g. `PS1` under `bash`) to show the current directory

Comment: cool idea. as long as I'm careful not to affect the performance of other programs that depend on cd.

Comment: You may want to set up PROMPT_COMMAND which would analyze current working directory and print out messages.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a script file in each folder that you want to have execute when entering the folder.  Then you can use the environment variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` to check for it and execute.  For example:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='test -x ./.prompt_command && ./.prompt_command'
```

This will execute a script called `.prompt_command` in the current folder only if it exists and has its executable bit set.